# programatically fire a click event for a point on highchart scatter plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Actually I am in a small requirement where in there is a scatter chart with a list of points and drop down list. When I select an item from the drop down list its corresponding data point click should be fired. And when I select a data point on the chart, some actions has to happen and the drop down list should get updated according to the selection.

Is there any way we can do this?

I've tried firePointClick, the event is coming as undefined, I want the event same as the event which we get when a manual click happens, is there any other way?? or any improvements

Answer (score 9):

It's not part of the API, but could be done using internal API function called `firePointEvent` that way:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click', event);
```

To do something similar for dropdown, you can use `point.events.click event handler`.

Comment: Can we give a Ctrl+Click on a point programatically using firePointEvent? Please note that when using firePointClick event is coming as undefined

Comment: Just simulate event as real one, so something like this: `chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click', {ctrlKey: true});`

Comment: @PawełFus I had a similar requirement but the above solution does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675306/firepointevent-not-working-while-firing-a-click-on-a-series-data-highchart

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to do what you want using the select event on the points. You can add an event handler to the select event in the chart (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.select)
but you can also trigger it using the API:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.select().

Comment: In this case a point is getting selected but its click event is not triggered