# Click a point on a highcharts graph from outside of the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highcharts graph that has click events bound to it in order to fire a dropdown on the same page.  It looks something like this:

```
 series: {
         point: {
             events: {
                 click: function(event) {
                         creditSideBar(event.point.y, formdate);
                 }
             }
         }
 };
```

This function then triggers some magic to a sidebar element.  What I'd like to be able to do is also trigger this click on the last point of the graph from an outside element within the same page.  For instance the user would click a link such as:

```
<a href="#point">Last Point</a>
```

This link would find the last plot point on the graph and fire a click event just as if the user was clicking on the point of the graph themselves.  Is is it possible to do with on highcharts?

Comment: See [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233681/programatically-fire-a-click-event-for-a-point-on-highchart-scatter-plot) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example to make select manipulations. If you want to make selection by some action or some expression, you can check attributes of data in series:

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,null]        
        }]
    });
    
    // button handler
    var i = 0;
    $('#button').click(function() {
        if (i == chart.series[0].data.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        var point = chart.series[0].data[i];
        point.select();
        chart.tooltip.refresh(point);
        i++;
    });
    $('#button2').click(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].data[i-1];
        point.select();
        var point2 = chart.series[0].data[chart.series[0].data.length-1];
        chart.tooltip.refresh(point2);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
<button id="button">Select point</button>
<button id="button2">Deselect point</button>
```