# Unable to trigger a click event on series data | Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to fire a click event in a series of data ( I am using Highcharts ) . My approach is as [follows](http://jsfiddle.net/4qeczbje/3/). I have the click event added in the plotOptions rather than point as it is done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/B87pZ/) which is working fine.

The issue (I think) is that firePointEvent is not working but clicking manually does fire the event.

```
var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click');
```

Is there something I am missing or am I wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Where did you find the `firePointEvent` function?

Comment: @RahulSharma I found it here http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/B87pZ/

Comment: Why don't you look at `console.log` you may find some pertinent error information there.  If not set a break point on your second line and go *into* the function and see what's going on there.  What I'm suggesting is also simple debugging stuff every Javascript developer should know how to do

Comment: Thank's @GeorgeJempty . You can see in my fiddle , I tried to log but there is nothing of that sort. Let me sum up what I am trying . I want to trigger the click event in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/1zw7ar17/) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case events can be referred:

```
chart.options.plotOptions.series.events.click(chart.series[series index]);
```

and get series inside chart like:

```
click: function(event) {
console.log(event);
alert(event.name + ' clicked\t');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asadsarwar89/5a64kd4p/)

Comment: Good find @AsadSarwar. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `chart.plotOptions.series.events.click`, but the original demo is using `chart.plotOptions.series.point.events.click`.

In case you want to fire an event programatically for a series, use:

```
Highcharts.fireEvent(chart.series[index], 'click', event);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qxjzzymb/

Comment: Thanks @PawelFus , I could solve my problem with both your answers.